# R: sum of rowSums off by one

Tags: r, csv

For my stats class, I'm using R to do some of the math for my term project. The class doesn't call for it, but I want to supplement myself by learning R, which is my weaker language.

Using this data: [skittle-data.csv](https://github.com/paul-nelson-baker/math-1040-stats-project/blob/master/skittle-data.csv) (Every row was an individual bag of skittles submitted by each student)

I'm trying to generate some charts and other things to satisfy the assignment. While doing so, I noticed that in determining the total number of skittles I was off by 1.

When I load the csv into a dataframe I make summations of the rows, and then sum those summations to get the total, like this:

```
skittles = read.csv("skittle-data.csv", header = TRUE)
columnTotals = colSums(skittles, na.rm=FALSE, dims = 1)
rowTotals = rowSums(skittles, na.rm=FALSE, dims = 1)
total = sum(rowTotals, na.rm=FALSE, dims = 1)

print("Column Totals")
print(columnTotals)

print("Row Totals (individual bags)")
print(rowTotals)

print('Total skittles')
print(total)
```

Running my code from my terminal outputs:

```
[1] "Column Totals"
   Red Orange Yellow  Green Purple
   269    289    296    295    300
[1] "Row Totals (individual bags)"
 [1] 62 62 60 60 60 62 59 61 57 59 62 59 59 62 64 62 63 61 60 60 58 59 60 58
[1] "Total skittles"
[1] 1450
```

Yet excel shows the total number of skittles is 1449.

[image: skittle data - excel file]

This is clearly user error on my part, but what is my mistake? Conceptually I think I've done this correctly so the only thing I can assume is that I've misunderstood some part of the summation functions (`colSums`, `rowSums`, or `sum`, etc)

Comment: @epi99 I'm not really sure how to interpret your comment, it really doesn't tell me much more than your opinion (remember, this is my weakest language, so I may be misunderstanding more than one thing. You'll have to be direct with what you are trying to tell me)... From this reference (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html) It seemed to indicate that it was required. I'll update the question to show most recent code not including dims, but that doesn't resolve the overarching issue.

Comment: Any named parameter you put in `sum` besides `na.rm` will be added: `sum(a = 1, b = 2, 3)` returns 6.

Comment: @alistaire cudos to you! Thank you for getting to the root of the issue, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the `dims = 1` parameter in `sum`.  When `x = c(1,1)`, then `sum(x)` gives you 2, but `sum(x, dims = 1)` equals 3.  Something about that parameter is giving an extra +1.

Comment: You barely beat @Eldioo to the punch, but you're right. It is that parameter. Barring someone breaking down the actual issue and explaining what that parameter is doing when I use it incorrectly, I'm going to choose your answer as the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: `dims` isn't a parameter in `sum()`. As @alistaire pointed out, `sum` is interpreting `dim = 1` as a vector and summing it along with `x` (hence why you have an extra 1. Look at `?sum`

Comment: @MikeH. Thanks for pointing out that comment, I hadn't yet seen it but that explains exactly what I didn't understand! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @alistaire.  I was trying to figure out what the `dims` parameter was doing, but since it's not a named parameter it just gets treated as part of the list of things to be added!

Answer (score 5):

Your error stems from your `sum` function:

```
total = sum(rowTotals, na.rm=FALSE, dims = 1)
```

It's interpreting the `dims = 1` as a number that is to be added. Remove it and it'll work as intended.